# How to modify bash script to iterate all possible matched pairs for desired output?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I need to iterate a list of objects to obtain all possible pair combinations. I found the below script and it works using a list in bash.

```
set -- value1 value2 "value with spaces"
for a; do
    shift
    for b; do
        printf "%s - %s\n" "$a" "$b"
    done
done
```

I'd like to modify it's starting not from a bash list but from a file (`txt` to `csv`) in which in the first column there is the name of the object to combine and in the second column, other information (I'd like to have also this in the output).

Input file:

```
ID,pKi
4a,10
4b,20
4c,30
```

Expected output file:

```
ID1,ID2,pKi1,pKi2
4a,4b,10,20
4a,4c,10,30
4b,4c,20,30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the two files into an array and use the same technique

```bsh
mapfile -t lines < input.file
last_index=$(( ${#lines[@]} - 1))

echo "ID1,ID2,pKi1,pKi2"

for ((i = 1; i < last_index; i++)); do
    for ((j = i+1; j <= last_index; j++)); do
        printf '%s,%s\n' "${lines[i]}" "${lines[j]}"
    done
done \
| awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$3,$2,$4}'   # rearrange the fields
```

---

@Tommaso reports:

> The script works but my output is this:
>
> ```
> 4a,4b,6.93
> ,7.29
> 4a,4c,6.93
> ,8.4
> 4a,4d,6.93
> ,7.67
> ```
>
> why does the last variable (pki2) wrap? Thanks.

Comment: I've edit your answer to showed my output problem.

Comment: Did you fail to include the `-t` option for mapfile?

Comment: Yes I did. How can I solved?

Comment: Use `mapfile -t varname` like I did in my answer.

Comment: You used mapfile -t  lines